# GWT - How to stop propagation from a child's event to its parent

Tags: events, gwt

I'm building a GWT application with a Tree.
Every tree items represent an object which has a boolean attribute that we can set through a checkbox displayed in the tree item itself.

I have a selection handler to do some stuff on my tree which gets called on click on every tree items.

What I want to do, is to prevent selection event to firing up when I'm clicking on the checkboxes ...

However, checkboxes don't have a SelectionHandler, so I tried to put a ClickEventHandler with event.stopPropagation(), but SelectionHandler is still getting called ...

EDIT: actually SelectionHandler is getting fired before ClickEventHandler anyway ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you also call `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Yes I tried. But if I put event.preventDefault(), the checkbox is not getting checked ...

Comment: After some debugging, I realized that the SelectionEvent on the TreeItem is being fired before ClickEvent of the checkbox ...

Answer (score 0):

You might consider following this method provided in the GWT documentation [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent.html#stopPropagation()). That should do the bit what you are interested in.

Comment: The problem is that we are dealing with 2 different events, and the parent (TreeItem)'s event is getting called before the child (Checkbox)'s event ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the separate click handler for the checkbox and use the event.StopProgation() there after inorder to prevent the event bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

For stop propagation from child's event to parent in GWT you need to use

```
event.stopPropagation();
```